# what is the proper way to scan local network by sending ARP request with scapy and capture the response?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, scapy

I wanted to made a network scanner which send ARP request to the broadcast mac address of ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff . 
my written code get response from all devices which are present in my local area network but when i run it again it always shows me less devices as compare to first scan.

```
def check_arping(ip):
  arp_request = scapy.ARP(pdst = ip)
broadcast = scapy.Ether(dst = "ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")
arp_request_broadcast = broadcast / arp_request
answered_list = scapy.srp(arp_request_broadcast, timeout = 1, verbose = False)[0]
clients_list = []

for eachelement in answered_list:
  client_dict = {
    "IP": eachelement[1].psrc,
    "MAC": eachelement[1].hwsrc
  }
clients_list.append(client_dict)
return clients_list
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems correct.

ARP results are very variable. In fact, some devices (most Apple devices for instance) do not reply to broadcasted requests or register gratuitous ARPs, for security reasons (and only reply to those when they need it). All devices may not always be available for scanning, resulting in the scan having different results.

What you could do:

- perform multiple scans with a timeout, and sum the results
- perform passive ARP scanning (it takes longer): sniffing the network for ARP packets between other clients, and registering the clients on each packet seen
- keep your current code :-)

Comment: can you please clarify what do you mean by performing multiple scan and summing up the result? thanks in advance :-)